# jsp keep checkbox value unless there is a change

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a checkbox on my jsp page, and I can check/uncheck it and with the onchange javascript function it will update accordingly after I click the save button. The issue with it at the moment is that it will always check what the checked value is (so even if I don't click on the checkbox, the checked value is 0, and when I click on the save button again without touching the checkbox it would think that the checkbox should be unchecked because the checked value is 0.) I don't want any changes to the checkbox value unless the value of the checkbox is different.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CompletedCheck${count}" tabindex="40" id="CompletedCheck${count}" title="Complete" onchange="checkedFields(${count})" Checked/>
<input type="hidden" name="Completed${count}" value="">

                    function checkedFields(count) {
                    var checkedFieldID = document.getElementById('CompletedCheck'+count).checked;

                    var completeFieldToSubmit = "Completed"+count;


                    if (checkedFieldID==false)
                        {

                            document.getElementById(completeFieldToSubmit).value =0;
                        }
                    if(checkedFieldID==true)
                        {
                            document.getElementById(completeFieldToSubmit).value= 1;
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Not able to understand what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? What do you mean by "I don't want any changes to the checkbox value unless the value of the checkbox is different."? Is it not like, if you check the check box ,it is checked?

Comment: What a strange way of checking if the checkbox is checked. Are the hidden input and JavaScript really necessary? Why don't you just check if `request.getParameter("CompletedCheck" + count)` returns non-null (=checked) or null (=unchecked)? This way you end up with much simpler code.

Comment: So the issue is that, the onchange command will check checkFieldID variable, which is false if the checkbox isn't checked, and true if it is checked irregardless of whether or not the checkbox is currently checked or not. So if the checkbox is currently checked but the user didn't touch anything and just hit save, the checkFieldID will be false, and it will checkbox to unchecked, which is not what I wanted. The checkbox should stay checked if it was checked before unless the user specifically set the box to unchecked.

Comment: Why it will be false? Once the checkbox is checked, `var checkedFieldID = document.getElementById('CompletedCheck'+count).checked;` will set it to true. right?

Comment: Yeah, seems like the issue is elsewhere, it probably has to do with the save button. I'm going to look into this matter further